# ERROR: Unknown column 'user0_.id' in 'field list'

Tags: spring, hibernate

So, I have two tables which are in a one-to-many relationship and when I try to log in, I get an error about some user0_id field. Problem is that I only send the username and password when the error gets triggered, so I am not sure what's causing it. I've read similar posts about this problem and it seems to have something to do with the mapping between entities and table. So, here are my entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="authority")
    private String authority;
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<Post> posts;

    ...

}
```

The other one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="content")
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

Can someone give me a pointer on what might be causing this? Because I don't see anything wrong and the names between the column and tables are the same.

Tables:

```
post
    1   id  int(11)         
    2   title   varchar(45)     
    3   content longtext    
    4   userId  int(11)         

user
    1   id  int(11)         
    2   email   varchar(45) 
    3   authority   varchar(45) 
    4   username    varchar(45) 
    5   password    varchar(45)
```

Error:

```
    ERROR: Unknown column 'user0_.id' in 'field list'
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at com.personal.services.LoginService.login(LoginService.java:24)
    at com.personal.controllers.HomeController.login(HomeController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.id' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: can you post the columns of the 2 tables

Comment: POST:
 1 id int(11)   
 2 title varchar(45)  
 3 content longtext  
 4 userId int(11)   

USER:
 1 id int(11)   
 2 email varchar(45) 
 3 authority varchar(45) 
 4 username varchar(45) 
 5 password varchar(45)

Comment: you should not use join column in both entities. in one of the you should use mappedBy. here in user class, remove join column and add mappedBy="user" in oneToMany annotation. try this and post here whatever it results

Comment: A small hint - you may use https://bootify.io to create your JPA / hibernate entities without such issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is indeed incorrect.

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private List<Post> posts;
```

That makes no sense. You're saying that a post refers to user by using the post.id column. That can't be correct, since `id` if the primary key of post.

It'a also incorrect because you want a bidirectional OneToMany association, and the one-side must thus be the inverse side of the association.

Here's the correct mapping:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Post> posts;
```

and in Post:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userId", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

Comment: I will try that later on. Thanks.

Comment: fk_post_user -> (column is usedId and table is post) -> (referenced table is user and referenced column is id)

Comment: Don't name your table USER. It's a reserved word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: ah, Jesus... what should I change then? Wait, are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: As I said: the name of the table USER.

Comment: The name of the table in the SQL database and the mapping, but not the entity?

Comment: right. MySQL doesn't know and care about the name of your entity.

Comment: It worked after I removed the mappedBy="user" and taking your advice. I am not sure if changing the table name did anything though, because I realized I was connecting to another database with a table user. LOL

Comment: Thanks again by the way.

Comment: Err, mappedBy="user" wasn't wrong. I think you're supposed to put it.

Comment: Why do you think it was wrong. That's what I told you to use in my answer. The mappedBy attribute contains the name of the field, in the target entity, that constitutes the owner side of the association. It's not a table name. This is documented: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy%28%29

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem though I don't think it would solve your problem.  I had to rename the database column to the unknown column name.  My error said something along the lines of "Unknown column 'category_id' in field list". The column name in the database was categoryId. When I change it to category_id everything work fine.