# I can't understand HQL to SQL translation

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb, hql

Why my simple 
`List<Shopping> products = session.createQuery("FROM Shopping").list();`

gives following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'shopping0_.product' in 'field list'

Here is mapping file Shopping.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "com.konrad.market.Shopping" table = "BASKETS">
  <meta attribute = "class-description">
     This class contains the employee detail.
  </meta>
<composite-id>
<key-property name="basketID" column="basketid" type="int"  />
<key-property name="productID" column="product" type="string" />
</composite-id>
<property name="quantity" column="quantity" type="int" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The table is:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| basketid | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| product  | varchar(30) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| quantity | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

basketid and product are also foreign keys.
Any ideas?

Comment: `name="productID"`  does changing this to `name="product"`  make any difference

Comment: No, as the field in the class is String productID.

Comment: show entity class also, for this table and whatever entity class it associated to

Comment: Sorry, I should post itclass Shopping implements Serializable
{
 private int basketID;
 private String productID;
 private int quantity;
 public Shopping()
 {
  quantity=1;
 }
 public int getBasketID()
 {
  return basketID;
 }
 public String getProductID()
 {
  return productID;
 }
 public int getQuantity()
 {
  return quantity;
 }
 public void setBasketID(int basketID)
 {
  this.basketID=basketID;
 }
 public void setProductID(String productID)
 {
  this.productID=productID;
 }
 public void setQuantity(int quantity)
 {
  this.quantity=quantity;
 }
}

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HThZS8fA

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478817/error-unknown-column-user0-id-in-field-list and make sure your entity class are mapped correctly. Note: You dont paste that in the comment or pastbin just edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Is this an example of where a 3rd party package makes things more complex rather than simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error - tha table doesn't have product col. Is it called productId ? Also, do you have the composite key defined in hbm file, in your db - on basketid and product.

Answer (score 0):

If basketid and product are foreign keys then you need to change the HBM mapping as I didn't see the mapping in hbm.