# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.cert_status' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have developed a spring boot web application and try to retrieve the User by user email from the MySQL database using the following controller implementation.

```java
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
@RestController()
public class UserController {
  private UserService userService;

  public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  
    @GetMapping("/users/email/{email}")
    public User findUserByPrincipalId(@PathVariable String email) {
        return userService.getUserByPrincipalId(email);
    }

}



@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {


  User getUserByPrincipalId(String principalId);

  Boolean existsByPrincipalId(String principalId);
}
```

this is the User entity class.

```java
@Entity(name = "sys_user")
@Table(name = "sys_user", schema = "mobile")
public class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "principal_id")
  private String principalId;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "passwd")
  private String password;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "prefixName")
  private String prefix = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "firstName")
  private String firstName = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "middleIntial")
  private String middleInitial = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "lastName")
  private String lastName = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "contactTypeId")
  private long contactTypeId = 0;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "phone")
  private String phone = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "fax")
  private String fax = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "mobile")
  private String mobile = "";

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "lastLogon")
  private Date lastLogon;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "lastIP")
  private String lastIP;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "status")
  private int status;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "loginsInPeriod")
  private int logInsInPeriod;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "createdOn")
  private Date createdOn;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "lastModified")
  private Date lastModified;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "secondaryemail")
  private String secondaryEmail;


  @Basic
  @Column(name = "salt")
  private String salt;
  
  @Basic
  @Column(name = "certStatus")
  private short certstatus;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private List<UserRole> userRoles;


...


}
```

properties.yaml

```yaml
spring:
  profiles: local
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jacplus?serverTimezone=UTC
    username: abc
    password: abc
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        naming:
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

this is the table structure in MySQL DB.

Table: sys_user

```sql
Columns:
id bigint(20) AI PK 
principal_id varchar(64) 
passwd varchar(128) 
prefixName char(8) 
firstName varchar(32) 
middleIntial char(1) 
lastName varchar(32) 
contactTypeId bigint(20) 
phone char(20) 
fax char(20) 
mobile char(20) 
lastLogon timestamp 
lastIP varchar(64) 
status smallint(6) 
loginsInPeriod int(11) 
createdOn datetime 
lastModified datetime 
secondaryemail varchar(64) 
salt varchar(64) 
certStatus smallint(6)
```

but when i call the following endpoint in the controller class.
http://localhost:8082/api/v1/users/email/test@gmail.com

I am getting the following exception in runtime.

```java
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java
:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConv
erter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)

    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
    'user0_.cert_status' in 'field list'
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
            ... 181 common frames omitted 2020-12-17 18:00:47,532 WARN  jacplus-subscriptions-service [XNIO-5 task-1] fcd93f1a-3503-4b
```

I spend lots of time on the internet to find a solution to this issue. but still, i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Just enable hibernate options `hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql` and `hibernate.use_sql_comments` and see what hql/sql cause of this exception.

Comment: @SternK  added this and updated the stack trace in the question

Comment: @SternK same question found in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478817/error-unknown-column-user0-id-in-field-list.what  that suggested to do is rename the database column name certStatus to cert_status. but i cant do this.