# ERROR: Unknown column '0_.' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, database

Hi I'm trying to make output of annual salary using below function:

```
List results=session.createQuery("select comp.annual_sales from employee").list();
```

My tables are defined as below

```
@Entity(name="company")
@Table(name="company")
public class company{
@Id
@Column(name="company_id")
private int company_id;

@Column(name="company_name")
private String company_name;

@Column(name="annual_sales")
private double annual_sales;

@Column(name="founding_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date founding_date;

/*@OneToMany(mappedBy = "comp", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<employee> emps; //= new HashSet<employee>();*/

public company(){}
public company(int company_id, String company_name, double annual_sales, Date founding_date){
    this.company_id=company_id;
    this.company_name=company_name;
    this.annual_sales=annual_sales;
    this.founding_date=founding_date;
}
```

}

```
@Entity(name="employee")
@Table(name="employee")
public class employee{
@Id
@Column(name="employee_id")
private int employee_id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String first_name;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String last_name;

@Column(name="salary")
private int salary;

@Column(name="company")
private int company;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="comp")
private company comp;

/*@OneToMany(mappedBy = "emp", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<account> accs; //= new HashSet<account>();*/

public employee(){}
public employee(int employee_id, String first_name, String last_name, int salary, int company){
    this.employee_id=employee_id;
    this.first_name=first_name;
    this.last_name=last_name;
    this.salary=salary;
    this.company=company;
}
```

}

```
@Entity(name="account")
@Table(name="account")
public class account{
@Id
@Column(name="account_id")
private int account_id;

@Column(name="bank_name")
private String bank_name;

@Column(name="opening_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date opening_date;

@Column(name="owner")
private int owner;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="emp")
private employee emp;

public account(){}
public account(int account_id, String bank_name, Date opening_date, int owner){
    this.account_id=account_id;
    this.bank_name=bank_name;
    this.opening_date=opening_date;
    this.owner=owner;
}
```

}

and the following error comes out:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'employee0_.comp' in 'where clause'
```

I have three major question here:

1. I have no column or attribute named 'employee0_' and why is it appearing in the error?
2. I have no 'where clause' sql function but why is such error appearing?
3. I've looked through many questions but it seemed nobody has similar problem with me nor they could solve my problem. The closest thing I could find was this: [ERROR: Unknown column 'user0_.id' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478817/error-unknown-column-user0-id-in-field-list)
   but adding @OnetoMany clause did not solve my problem.
   How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

`employee0_` is just an alias, that's used by Hibernate in the query. The error itself refers to the column `comp`, which Hibernate cannot find in the employee table. The where clause is added, because Hibernate needs to load the company entity, which is referred to in the employee entity.

So to fix the error, you should make sure that you actually have a column named `comp` in the employee table, and if not, either use the correct name in the annotation or create the column.